# Check dimensionality of complex unit in pint

Tags: python, units-of-measurement, pint

I am trying to check for dimensionality of a unit that is complex such as volume (m^3) or velocity (ft/min). How can I use the "pint.check()" method to see if a quantity is of that type of dimension?

This is what I have tried:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

volume = 4.3 * ureg.gal
```

Doing this makes sense:

```py
volume.dimensionality
Out[3]: <UnitsContainer({'[length]': 3.0})>
```

So I tried the "check" function but I don't know how to do it for volume:

```py
volume.check('[length]', 3)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jle\...\interactiveshell.py", line 3291, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4722a8cb0b0c>", line 1, in <module>
    volume.check('[length]', 3)
TypeError: check() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Did you try `volume.check('[length]')`?  Or `volume.check(3)`?

Comment: I tried both of these and they both return False. I would expect the check('[length]') to return false since that is not Length*length*length for volume. The second option "volume.check(3)" just returns False so I'm not even sure what that is doing. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh I figured it out. I need to do ```volume.check('[length]**3')``` and that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for volume using `check('[volume]')`:

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

volume = 4.3 * ureg.gal

# Returns True
volume.check('[volume]')
```

You can check for velocity using `check('[length]/[time]')`:

```
velocity = 1 * ureg.feet / ureg.second

# Returns True
velocity.check('[length]/[time]')
```